# How can I include hidden DIVs using CSS without them take up space?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple MVC 5 page with a single dropdown list.  Based upon the selection made from this dropdown list I enable visibility for one of three divs on the page.  The problem I am running into is each div takes space on the page, even if it is not visible.  So when I select something from dropdown list that causes the second div to be visible I will see that content shifted down on the page.

Here is the code from the Controller to create the data for the dropdown list.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var searchBy = new List<SearchBy>
  {
    new SearchBy { Name = "Email Address", Value = "EmailAddress" },
    new SearchBy { Name = "Last name, First name", Value = "Name" },
    new SearchBy { Name = "Username", Value = "Username" }
  };

  ViewBag.SearchByOptions = new SelectList(searchBy, "Value", "Name");

  return View();
}
```

Here is my markup for the Index.cshtml

```
@{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Make all three <div>s hidden when the page loads...
        document.getElementById("searchByEmail").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("searchByName").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("searchByUsername").style.visibility = "hidden";
    });

    function searchBy(selectedItem) {
        if (selectedItem == "EmailAddress") {
            // Make visible
            document.getElementById("searchByEmail").style.visibility = "visible";
            // Make in-visible
            document.getElementById("searchByName").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("searchByUsername").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }                

        if (selectedItem == "Name") {
            // Make visible
            document.getElementById("searchByName").style.visibility = "visible";
            // Make in-visible
            document.getElementById("searchByEmail").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("searchByUsername").style.visibility = "hidden";
        } 

        if (selectedItem == "Username") {
            // Make visible
            document.getElementById("searchByUsername").style.visibility = "visible";
            // Make in-visible
            document.getElementById("searchByEmail").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("searchByName").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };
</script>
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>    
    Search for existing users by: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", (SelectList)ViewBag.SearchByOptions, "-- Select One --", new { onchange = "searchBy($('#SelectedItem').val());" }) 
</div>

<div id="searchByEmail">
    Emails...
</div>

<div id="searchByName">
    Names...
</div>

<div id="searchByUsername">
    Usernames...
</div>
}
```

I am not sure what trick is needed to get all of the divs to take the same "real estate" on the page as I will only be showing one of them at a time.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you use jQuery, try:

```
@{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#searchByEmail").hide();
        $("#searchByName").hide();
        $("#searchByUsername").hide();
    });

    function searchBy(selectedItem) {
        if (selectedItem == "EmailAddress") {
            $("#searchByEmail").show();
            $("#searchByName").hide();
            $("#searchByUsername").hide();
        }                
        if (selectedItem == "Name") {
            $("#searchByName").show();
            $("#searchByEmail").hide();
            $("#searchByUsername").hide();
        } 

        if (selectedItem == "Username") {
            $("#searchByUsername").show();
            $("#searchByEmail").hide();
            $("#searchByName").hide();
        }
    };
</script>
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>    
    Search for existing users by: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedItem", (SelectList)ViewBag.SearchByOptions, "-- Select One --", new { onchange = "searchBy($('#SelectedItem').val());" }) 
</div>
```

Also, check what is the difference between CSS rules:

```
visibility:hidden
```

and

```
display:none
```

The first just hide the element, but preserve the placeholder the same size as it is visible.
The second removes it from the size and dimension calculations.

Comment: Thanks GRSEV, exactly what I was looking for.  Quickest answer EVER! :-) I'll mark as answer in a few minutes when it allow me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.style.display = "block"; /* or none to hide it */
```